# UITableView with No Entries

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a question. In my app I have a TableView with a list with something, I want when I delete the last record to show on TableView "No more data". Thanks!

Comment: Add a label(hide it initially in viewdidload using your `label.hidden = YES`). When you delete last record hide your table using `yourTable.hidden = YES` and show label using `your label.hidden = NO`....Better answers below though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(self.searchUserResultList count==0))
    {
        // Display a message when the table is empty
        UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-15, self.view.frame.size.height/2 , self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

        messageLabel.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        messageLabel.text = @"NO SEARCH RESULTS" ;
        messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Palatino-Italic" size:23];
        [messageLabel sizeToFit];
        messageLabel.tag = 222;

        messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-(messageLabel.frame.size.width/2), self.view.frame.size.height/2, messageLabel.frame.size.width, messageLabel.frame.size.height);

        [self.view addSubview:messageLabel];

        self.tableView.hidden = YES;

        return 0;
    }

    for (UIView* b in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if(b.tag == 222)
        {
            [b removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    self.tableView.hidden = NO;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jenny, is working perfectly... from all answers just yours is working.... Thanks to all who helped me!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView=header;  //UIView
 self.tableView.tableFooterView=footer//UIView
```

You can check in condition for last record if deleted and add a header OR footer

Use this methods, and create a header OR Footer View to show No more data

Answer (score 0):

You could use the header or footer for that, e.g.:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) {
        return @"No more data";
    }
    return nil;
}
```

If you don't like this, create a label, add it to the view and show/hide it based on the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by using your original data array count like below

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(arrData.count == 0 )
        return 1;


    return arrData.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if(arrData.count == 0){
        cell.titleLabel.text=@"No Data";
    }else{
        //Your normal configurations
    }



    return cell;
}
```

When you delete all the data from your data array, it will be blank, and when you reload the tableView after last deleted data, if will return one cell that you can show as `No Data` row.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.